# EF6 vs Entity Framework Core : Insert an entity without resetting the primary key (identity) to zero

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

EF6: inserting an entity that already has a value for the primary key works and assigns a new value to the primary key.

EF Core : it tries to insert the value of the primary key and obviously fails with a **SqlException**:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Asset' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

The workaround I found is to reset the PK to the default value (0 for an int).

Example :

```
        Asset asset = new Asset
        {
            Id = 3,
            Name = "Toto",
        };      

        using (AppDbContext context = new AppDbContext())
        {
            asset.Id = 0; // needs to be reset
            context.Assets.Add(asset);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I'm migrating a solution from EF 6 to EF Core and I'd like to avoid resetting manually all the IDs in case of an insertion. The example above is really simple, sometimes I have a whole graph to insert, in my case that would mean resetting all the PKs and FKs of the graph.

The only automatic solution I can think of is using reflection to parse the whole graph and reset the IDs. But i don't think that's very efficient...

My question: how to disable that behaviour globally?

Comment: I'd pretty much say that because of the terrible decision to reinsert a object with a duplicate key, trying to make the new system do the same thing is also a terrible idea.  The right choice of action is to fix all the code correctly.

Comment: That's not my code, my job is to port to ef core, not to refactor.

Comment: I would personally bring it up with whoever.  Knowing about *literally bad code* and just trying to make it work, isn't a company I'd want to work for.  If that's your case I'm truly sorry, I hope someone knows how to solve that problem then.

Comment: "My job is to port, not to fix" isn't a good attitude, my advice to you.

Comment: Just a wild guess - have you tried changing the entity state to modified instead of add?

Comment: Well hopefully that's not my company, just a random client that I won't ever see again in a month, He does not want to hear about refactoring +unit testing, with a cheap budget that's what you get : zero fixing. My job is to provide different scenarii with different deadlines I don't decide I suggest. So go complain to him and teach him how to run a business.

Comment: @TheUknown that would modify the existing entry.

Comment: Ok, I just assumed there are no existing entries and you are migrating it. nvm

Comment: Huh. My first thought was to use an interceptor (because that's super easy). Turns out, that's not supported by EF Core. Damn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately currently (as of EF Core 2.0.1) this behavior is not controllable. I guess it's supposed to be improvement from EF6 since it allows you to perform identity inserts.

Fortunately EF Core is build on service based architecture which allows you ( (although not so easily) to replace almost every aspect. In this case, the responsible service is called `IValueGenerationManager` and is implemented by [`ValueGenerationManager`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/dev/src/EFCore/ChangeTracking/Internal/ValueGenerationManager.cs) class. The lines that provide the aforementioned behavior are

```
private static IEnumerable<IProperty> FindPropagatingProperties(InternalEntityEntry entry)    
    => entry.EntityType.GetProperties().Where(    
        property => property.IsForeignKey()    
                    && property.ClrType.IsDefaultValue(entry[property]));

private static IEnumerable<IProperty> FindGeneratingProperties(InternalEntityEntry entry)    
    => entry.EntityType.GetProperties().Where(    
        property => property.RequiresValueGenerator()    
                    && property.ClrType.IsDefaultValue(entry[property]));
```

specifically the `&& property.ClrType.IsDefaultValue(entry[property])` condition.

It would have been nice if these methods were `virtual`, but they are not, so in order to remove that check you basically need to copy almost all code.

Add the following code to a new code file in your project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static DbContextOptionsBuilder UseEF6CompatibleValueGeneration(this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IValueGenerationManager, EF6CompatibleValueGeneratorManager>();
            return optionsBuilder;
        }
    }
}

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal
{
    public class EF6CompatibleValueGeneratorManager : ValueGenerationManager
    {
        private readonly IValueGeneratorSelector valueGeneratorSelector;
        private readonly IKeyPropagator keyPropagator;

        public EF6CompatibleValueGeneratorManager(IValueGeneratorSelector valueGeneratorSelector, IKeyPropagator keyPropagator)
            : base(valueGeneratorSelector, keyPropagator)
        {
            this.valueGeneratorSelector = valueGeneratorSelector;
            this.keyPropagator = keyPropagator;
        }

        public override InternalEntityEntry Propagate(InternalEntityEntry entry)
        {
            InternalEntityEntry chosenPrincipal = null;
            foreach (var property in FindPropagatingProperties(entry))
            {
                var principalEntry = keyPropagator.PropagateValue(entry, property);
                if (chosenPrincipal == null)
                    chosenPrincipal = principalEntry;
            }
            return chosenPrincipal;
        }

        public override void Generate(InternalEntityEntry entry)
        {
            var entityEntry = new EntityEntry(entry);
            foreach (var property in FindGeneratingProperties(entry))
            {
                var valueGenerator = GetValueGenerator(entry, property);
                SetGeneratedValue(entry, property, valueGenerator.Next(entityEntry), valueGenerator.GeneratesTemporaryValues);
            }
        }

        public override async Task GenerateAsync(InternalEntityEntry entry, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var entityEntry = new EntityEntry(entry);
            foreach (var property in FindGeneratingProperties(entry))
            {
                var valueGenerator = GetValueGenerator(entry, property);
                SetGeneratedValue(entry, property, await valueGenerator.NextAsync(entityEntry, cancellationToken), valueGenerator.GeneratesTemporaryValues);
            }
        }

        static IEnumerable<IProperty> FindPropagatingProperties(InternalEntityEntry entry)
        {
            return entry.EntityType.GetProperties().Where(property => property.IsForeignKey());
        }

        static IEnumerable<IProperty> FindGeneratingProperties(InternalEntityEntry entry)
        {
            return entry.EntityType.GetProperties().Where(property => property.RequiresValueGenerator());
        }

        ValueGenerator GetValueGenerator(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property)
        {
            return valueGeneratorSelector.Select(property, property.IsKey() ? property.DeclaringEntityType : entry.EntityType);
        }

        static void SetGeneratedValue(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property, object generatedValue, bool isTemporary)
        {
            if (generatedValue == null) return;
            entry[property] = generatedValue;
            if (isTemporary)
                entry.MarkAsTemporary(property, true);
        }
    }
}
```

then override `OnConfiguring` in your `DbContext` derived class and add the following line:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    // ...
    optionsBuilder.UseEF6CompatibleValueGeneration();
}
```

and that's it - problem solved.

Comment: I've tried it with a small project at home (I'm not at work)... wow you're a pro. Thanks for saving my week-end!

Comment: @IvanStoev, This is really a great answer. It's 4 yrs ago but this is the closest one I got so far to resolving my issue. If you are still familiar with it, hope you can help me on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72699137/ef-core-cannot-save-more-than-1-entity-with-tpt-approach)

Answer (score 2):

Since EF Core doesn't support interceptors, my recommendation is to "hack it".

If you overwrite the `SaveChanges` method you can provide this functionality on **every** save without a massive refactor.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    //...

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var dbEntityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries<Asset>()
                                                   .Where(t => t.State == EntityState.Added))
        {
            dbEntityEntry.Entity.Id = default(int);
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This may end up needing a loop for each type, or maybe you can get creative, but generally speaking this will accomplish what you want without making massive changes to your business methods.