# EF Core - Cannot save more than 1 entity with TPT approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, table-per-type

We are migrating our application .NET Framework and EF6 to .NET 6 and EF Core v6.

Our application uses the TPT approach in one of our models. I have read all the articles related to TPT and some questions here on SO but it seems it does not provide a resolution to my concern.

I have a sample code here based on this [article](https://nishanc.medium.com/inheritance-strategy-in-entity-framework-core-5-46345e90e297).

```
    public class TPTUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class TPTStudent : TPTUser
    {
        public string CGPA { get; set; }
        public string Major { get; set; }
    }

    public class TPTTeacher : TPTUser
    {
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string Speciality { get; set; }
    }
```

My DbContext:

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<TPTUser> TPTUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TPTStudent> TPTStudents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TPTTeacher> TPTTeachers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Foo");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<TPTUser>().ToTable("TPTUsers");
            modelBuilder.Entity<TPTUser>()
                .HasKey(p => p.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<TPTUser>()
                .Property(p => p.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .UseIdentityColumn();

            modelBuilder.Entity<TPTStudent>().ToTable("TPTStudents");
            modelBuilder.Entity<TPTTeacher>().ToTable("TPTTeachers");
        }
    }
```

I am trying to add 2 `TPTStudent` instances with the PK having a value (this is just a random int value). Initially, our application generates the model from the client-side and by default, it has a value on the PK.

This is the code for adding the TPTStudent:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new TestContext())
            {

                var std = new List<TPTStudent>
                {
                    new TPTStudent()
                    {
                        Id = 422,
                        Username = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                        Email = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                        CGPA = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                        Major = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
                    },
                    new TPTStudent()
                    {
                        Id = 412,
                        Username = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                        Email = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                        CGPA = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                        Major = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
                    }
                };

                context.TPTStudents.AddRange(std);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

After hitting the SaveAsync, it returns this error:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TPTUsers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF
```

I am aware that the cause of this issue is that the EF Core assumes that if you set the key value, then that's the key value of that entity.

My main goal is to add these entities successfully and EF Core ignoring the values `Id` property. The values for `Id` should be generated on the database because its column is set to IDENTITY.

I have tried using `ValueGeneratedOnAdd`,`UseIdentityColumn`, setting `IsTemporary` to true (before SaveChanges), but none of it seems to work.

If what I want to achieve is impossible, then my last resort will be this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751109/13726696).

EDIT: I found this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47600987/13726696) and it is exactly what I need. Does anybody knows how to implement this on EF Core v6?

Comment: IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF on table (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), 

context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.TPTUsers ON");
    context.SaveChanges();
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.TPTUsers OFF");

Comment: @SilentTremor The actual PK column is on auto-increment/identity. It will also be expensive to turn it on/off everytime a saving occurs. Unfortunately, that will not work for me but thanks!

Comment: How about setting `Id` to zero in SaveChanges?

Comment: Then you are asking wrong question, IDENTITY_INSERT has nothing to do with entity framework, when is off auto-increment generates next value in PK, when is on at insert PK must be specified, plain and simple. To dictate PK value with out IDENTITY_INSERT ON, good luck. Not sure what exactly is expensive? Oh and another recommendation do it a transaction scope in case something goes wrong, like duplicate PK

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I tried setting the Id to 0 using `entry.Property("Id").CurrentValue = (int)default` before SaveChanges and I encountered this error `The instance of entity type 'TPTStudent' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked`.

Comment: @SilentTremor Apologies, my question is not clear. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happend to me.
The problem is, id is increasing by database, and on the other hand , entity framework is trying insert same id.
Firstly, you can solve it by disabling the autoincrement from database.
or you can apply my second solution.

How i solved it.

```
 public class TPHUser
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

the model should be like this.Furthermore, you should enable the identity insert .
then you should insert data, after that you should disable the idendity insert.
But the main thing, you should do it in one transaction to keep the data consistency.
the below code for a transaction insert.i m using unitOfWork. but if you want , you can use same codes without unitOfWork.

```
   using (var transaction = unitOfWork._context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            await unitOfWork._context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("SET IDENTITY_INSERT TPHUser ON");
            var std = new List<TPTStudent>
           {
            new TPTStudent()
            {

                Username = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                Email = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                CGPA = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                Major = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
            },
            new TPTStudent()
            {

                Username = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                Email = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                CGPA = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                Major = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
            }
           }

            var ss = await unitOfWork.TPTStudent_Repostory.AddRange(std);
            await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();

            await unitOfWork._context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("SET IDENTITY_INSERT TPHUser OFF");
            transaction.Commit();
        }
```